# Spring Security: exclude an URL from SiteMinder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, siteminder

I have a question about Spring Security and SiteMinder.

Usually I use SM_USER header for all my requests to all my pages but this time I need to exclude one URL: it will send a request without SM_USER header.

I use Java Congifuration:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    // for class CustomUserDetailsService I configured how I get the list of 
    // user authorities with the content of SM_USER header

    userDetailsService = new CustomUserDetailsService();
    UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>(
            userDetailsService);

    preAuthenticatedProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    preAuthenticatedProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(wrapper);
    auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedProvider);


    log.debug("global security configuration was successfull");
}
```

And then I add authorities for different URLs:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      

    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteMinderFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    siteMinderFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SM_USER");
    siteMinderFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());   
    http.addFilter(siteMinderFilter);
    ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry = http.authorizeRequests();
//adding an authority to URL containing SM_USEr_URL
    registry.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**/SM_USER_URL/**").hasAuthority("authority1"); 

//here I try to exclude the URL from Siteminder.
    registry.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**/ExcludedPage/**").permitAll();
}
```

My problem is that for the request to ExcludedPage URL I don't get anything except the exception:

```
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException: SM_USER header not found in request.
```

And I don't how can I really set up filter for this page that it doesn't need any SM_USER header at all.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for each URL that should **accept** siteminder add

```
http.antMatcher(SM_USER_URL).addFilter(siteMinderFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the correct behavior of `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter`. Try `setExceptionIfHeaderMissing` to false like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      

    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteMinderFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    siteMinderFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SM_USER");
    siteMinderFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager()); 
  ->siteMinderFilter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
    ...
```